# Loading ActiveX control dynamically onto page using query widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, activex

I have an active X control that looks something like this:

```
<object id="activeX" height="100%" width="100%" classid="myClass" >
    <param name="name" value="myControlName" />
    <param name="details" value="interestingDetails" />
    <param name="a" value="a" />
    <param name="b" value="b" />
</object>
```

Instead of having this html live on my page, I'd like to insert it dynamically using a jquery widget.

I could do something like this:

```
myObject.id = "activeX";
        myObject.height = "100%";
        myObject.width = "100%";
        myObject.classid = "myClass";


    var param1 = document.createElement('param');
    param1.setAttribute('name', 'name');
    param1.setAttribute('value', 'myControlName');
    myObject.appendChild(param1);

    var param2 = document.createElement('param');
    param2.setAttribute('name', 'details');
    param2.setAttribute('value', 'interestingDetails');
    myObject.appendChild(param2);

    var param3 = document.createElement('param');
    param3.setAttribute('name', 'a');
    param3.setAttribute('value', 'a');
    myObject.appendChild(param3);

    var param4 = document.createElement('param');
    param4.setAttribute('name', 'b');
    param4.setAttribute('value', 'b');
    myObject.appendChild(param4);
```

and then attach that object to something on my page.

Or i could simply append the html to my page like:

```
 $('#div').append('<object id="activeX" height="100%" width="100%" classid="myClass" >')
    .append('<param name="name" value="myControlName" />')
    .append('<param name="details" value="interestingDetails" />')
    .append('<param name="a" value="a" />')
    .append('<param name="b" value="b" />')
    .append('</object>');
```

Niether of these work. When i try and call the active X control that I just loaded onto the page using either of the above 2 methods, I get object doesn't exist.

Calling the active X objects, when I write the  straight the my HTML works. But not when I load this object from a widget.

--Does anyone know a way to load activeX controls onto a page using jquery widgets?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check this: [Possible to append a ActiveX control to a page using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065828/possible-to-append-a-activex-control-to-a-page-using-javascript?rq=1)

I don't know what activex you are using but I can suggest a common approach:

- Let the activex load in the page.
- Just keep it hidden
- If there is start/stop kind of control, use it on "div" hide/show

This way, you'll ensure user gets a choice to allow activex during page load and can get content while showing the div element